# Difference between OpenOrCreateDatabse and to use the database helper class?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I was watching derek banas tutorials and he used OpenOrCreate to create the database, here is the code of the java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

SQLiteDatabase contactsDB = null;

Button createDBButton, addContactButton, deleteContactButton, getContactsButton,
        deleteDBButton;
EditText nameEditText, emailEditText, contactListEditText, idEditText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    createDBButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createDBButton);
    addContactButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addContactButton);
    deleteContactButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deleteContactButton);
    getContactsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getContactsButton);
    deleteDBButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deleteDBButton);
    nameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
    emailEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailEditText);
    contactListEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contactListEditText);
    idEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.idEditText);

}

public void createDatabase(View view) {

    try{

        // Opens a current database or creates it
        // Pass the database name, designate that only this app can use it
        // and a DatabaseErrorHandler in the case of database corruption

        SQLiteDatabase contactsDB= this.openOrCreateDatabase("MyContacts", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        // Execute an SQL statement that isn't select
        contactsDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contacts " +
                "(id integer primary key, name VARCHAR, email VARCHAR);");

        // The database on the file system
        File database = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("MyContacts.db");

        // Check if the database exists
        if (database.exists()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Database Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Database Missing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    catch(Exception e){

        Log.e("CONTACTS ERROR", "Error Creating Database");

    }

    // Make buttons clickable since the database was created
    addContactButton.setClickable(true);
    deleteContactButton.setClickable(true);
    getContactsButton.setClickable(true);
    deleteDBButton.setClickable(true);

}

public void addContact(View view) {

    // Get the contact name and email entered
    String contactName = nameEditText.getText().toString();
    String contactEmail = emailEditText.getText().toString();

    // Execute SQL statement to insert new data
    contactsDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO contacts (name, email) VALUES ('" +
            contactName + "', '" + contactEmail + "');");

}

public void getContacts(View view) {

    // A Cursor provides read and write access to database results
    Cursor cursor = contactsDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM contacts", null);

    // Get the index for the column name provided
    int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex("id");
    int nameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex("name");
    int emailColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex("email");

    // Move to the first row of results
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    String contactList = "";

    // Verify that we have results
    if(cursor != null && (cursor.getCount() > 0)){

        do{
            // Get the results and store them in a String
            String id = cursor.getString(idColumn);
            String name = cursor.getString(nameColumn);
            String email = cursor.getString(emailColumn);

            contactList = contactList + id + " : " + name + " : " + email + "\n";

            // Keep getting results as long as they exist
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());

        contactListEditText.setText(contactList);

    } else {

        Toast.makeText(this, "No Results to Show", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        contactListEditText.setText("");

    }

}

public void deleteContact(View view) {

    // Get the id to delete
    String id = idEditText.getText().toString();

    // Delete matching id in database
    contactsDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM contacts WHERE id = " + id + ";");

}

public void deleteDatabase(View view) {

    // Delete database
    this.deleteDatabase("MyContacts");

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    contactsDB.close();

    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

but when I run this code, it shows me a **toast** message that *database is missing*, I will show you the xml also:

My XML...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Create Database"
    android:id="@+id/createDBButton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="createDatabase"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add Contact"
    android:id="@+id/addContactButton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/createDBButton"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/createDBButton"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:onClick="addContact"
    android:clickable="false" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Delete Contact"
    android:id="@+id/deleteContactButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/createDBButton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="deleteContact"
    android:clickable="false"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Get Contacts"
    android:id="@+id/getContactsButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/createDBButton"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/deleteContactButton"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/deleteContactButton"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:onClick="getContacts"
    android:clickable="false"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/nameEditText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/deleteContactButton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nameEditText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/idEditText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/emailEditText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:hint="ID to Delete"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Delete Database"
    android:id="@+id/deleteDBButton"
    android:onClick="deleteDatabase"
    android:layout_below="@+id/idEditText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:clickable="false" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/contactListEditText"
    android:lines="8"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

My problem also that I checked the website for tutorials points they didn't use anything from this code. Instead they use a database helper class and they used Insert methods and create ....  and they use them in other classes.

So what's the difference between derek banas tutorials and Tutorials point website and why the code of derek banas gave me this error *"Database is missing"* when I press on the create database button???

Comment: @vogella as an excellent tutorial on using SQLite on Android, maybe you should give it a look: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html  In general avoid `openOrCreateDatabase` and prefer solutions using SQLiteOpenHelper

Answer (score 0):

`SQLiteOpenHelper` versions database files so you can migrate them across schema changes. It also opens the database file for you.

`openOrCreateDatabase()` just opens/creates the database file, and `SQLiteOpenHelper` uses that internally.

Why you get "Database is missing" is because you create/open database file called `MyContacts` but test for the existence of another file `MyContacts.db`.

Comment: thanks man it works. But now my new error is with the insert statement it stops the application whenever a press the add contact button

Answer (score -1):

Everything looks fine but your query for creating table in database is wrong and as you're performing every operation on it, that shows error

```
contactsDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contacts " +
                "(id integer primary key, name VARCHAR, email VARCHAR);");
```

instead of using that use this

```
contactsDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contacts " +
                "(_id INTEGER primary key, name VARCHAR, email VARCHAR);");
```

as the way you've passed id is wrong. it should be as `_id` according to standards and also use integer as `INTEGER`

Good luck

Comment: `_id` is a standard, but it's not necessary. And I don't think the case matters on the column type, so I'm not sure you've answered the question

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for your guidence. I've answered it as per my android coding experience and the way i've used it. But will keep this in mind as well thanks.